# Как просмотреть комментарий к методу в Android Studio (intellij IDEA)?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Насколько я знаю Android Studio разработана на **intellij IDEA**, так что не знакомых с Android studio, но знакомых с **intellij IDEA** также прошу помочь с этим вопросом, заранее спасибо!

Хочется, чтобы при наведении на метод выводились документированные комментарии к нему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Документация по методу можно вызывать сочетанием клавиш <kbd>[Ctrl]</kbd> + <kbd>[Q]</kbd>, предварительно установив курсор на метод. Подробнее в [официальной документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-inline-documentation.html)

Comment: Спасибо, ваш метод работает

Answer (score 6):

В настройках редактора смотрите

[image: Настройки]

Comment: Ваш метод также работает